# Why am I getting Run-Time Error 4605 when pasting Cells from Excel into Outlook using Rich Text Formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, copy-paste, rtf

I'm trying to build a macro that takes AR reports for each sales rep in the current week's workbook and exports each sheet to a new email. Each Rep has exactly one sheet, named their initials, dedicated to them, and the sheet tabs are sorted alphabetically by those initials inside of the workbook (AB is sheet 1, BC is sheet 2, CD is sheet 3, etc.). [This is the standard report example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69V0t.png), [This is 'BC' since it's the special sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQzky.png), [And this is one that's just sorted alphabetically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzki3.png)

This is the process for my editing prior to this macro;

- QuickBooks exports the AR sheets from Current to oldest range: "Current, 1-30, 31-60, 61-90, >90"
- Some sheets get organized alphabetically by company instead of by aging range

  - BC's sheet has columns that get deleted, for reasons known only to those who came before me.
- All the sheets get pasted into an email per rep. one sheet per email per rep.

  - if the sheet was not re-sorted alphabetically, the date ranges need to be pasted in reverse order: ">90, 61-90, 31-60, 1-30, Current"
- These also need to be pasted as "Rich Text Format" for reasons unknown to me, not just the standard paste.

I've got this code where it does copy and paste successfully, up until a point.

This is my current code I've got. It currently gets to 5 sheets; AB, BC, CD, DE, and EF. AB is standard, BC is the sorted and has columns deleted, CD & DE are both alphabetically sorted, and EF is standard. The emails start fine, with AB coming out as desired. Then I get 3 Emails with BC, skipping CD and DE, and then I get an error message on EF. I've added the message in the comments of my code below, directly above the line that the debugger points to.

```
Sub PasteARtoEmail()

    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRange As Object
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim intAge As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim strWB As String
    
    'grab the name of the current week's workbook
    strWB = InputBox("Enter the name of the current week's AR report, without the file extension.", "Current AR Report")
    Set wb1 = Workbooks(strWB & ".xlsx")
    
    'count how may reps have worksheets in the book
    For i = 1 To wb1.Worksheets.Count
    
        'dont put KT's AR in an email unless it's another country's book
        If wb1.Worksheets(i).Name = "KT" Then
            If ws1.Index > 5 Then
                i = i + 1
            End If
        End If
        
        'Now as long as it's not KT in domestics, we run it
        Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets(i)
        
        'open the new email for this sales rep
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)
        With olMail
                
                .display
                
                .Subject = "Weekly AR Report - " & strWB & " - "
                
                Set OlInsp = .getInspector
                Set wdDoc = OlInsp.WordEditor
                
                olFormatRichText = 3
                .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        End With
        
        'A2 will always say "Current" for the Reps who aren't sorted alphabetically.
        'If they just get the basic QB export, this will be what's run.
        'This the majority of Reps.
        If ws1.Cells(2, 1).Value Like "Current" Then
        
            'Grab the last real row with any info, QB likes to insert some extra at the end
            lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            'lastrow is the total of all agings, this grabs the >90 total row, the period where we start.
            intTotal = lastrow - 1
            
            'Stops when the row value of the total's gets below the
            '"current" mark, aka row 1
            Do While intTotal > 2
                
                'ensures that there is a blank between the total and age cells, if so then there's an invoice during the period
                'and that invoice needs to be noted in the email to the rep
                'My hope is that this loops for every aging section
                If Cells(intTotal - 1, 1).Value = "" Then
            
                    intAge = ws1.Cells(intTotal, 1).End(xlUp).Row
             
                    Set rng = ws1.Range(Cells(intAge, 1).Address, Cells(intTotal, 23).Address)
                    
                    rng.Copy
                    
                    'This is where I am probably missing something. The Outlook commands from excel VBA are new to me, and I'm
                    'probably missing something.
                    With olMail
                    
                        Set oRange = wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
                        
                        'This line is where I get an error code:
                        '"Run-time error '4605'
                        '
                        'This method or property is not available here because the Clipboard is
                        'empty or not valid"
                        oRange.Paste
                        
                        oRange.InsertParagraphAfter
                    End With
                    
                    intTotal = intAge - 1
                
                'if there's not a blank, then there is no invoices in that period, skip to the next total line
                Else
                    intTotal = intTotal - 2
                End If
                
            Loop
                
        Else
        
            'If Current isn't in A2, then it's one of the alphabetically
            'sorted AR reports. BC is the outlier for formatting, so
            'we'll check for him first.
            'All we need to do is grab the whole sheet's contents and paste it in one big block in the email
            If ws1.Name = "BC" Then
            
                lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
             
                Set rng = ws1.Range("A1:K" & lastrow)
                
                rng.Copy
                
                With olMail
                
                    Set oRange = wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
                    oRange.Paste
                    
                    oRange.InsertParagraphAfter
                End With
                            
            'And then we hit the few other Reps who get sorted Alphabetically instead of by aging
            'Again, just need to grab the one huge block and paste it.
            Else
                
                lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row
             
                Set rng = ws1.Range("D1:W" & lastrow)
                
                With olMail
                
                    Set oRange = wdDoc.Paragraphs(wdDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
                    oRange.Paste
                    
                    oRange.InsertParagraphAfter
                End With
                
            End If
        End If
    
    'I don't know if this is necessary? is this part of what's throwing the error?
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

I will freely admit to being very new to VBA and coding in general, so this may be an issue of not knowing a method or something that helps simplify this process. I do notice in the locals view tab that "oRange"'s values all say that "the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable, but I don't know why it's popping up after 5 emails are built.

So, Why is that error popping up? Is it something to do with how I'm checking the contents? What can I try to make this work properly?

Comment: Hard to diagnose without being able to run the code on the data in the relevant Worksheets but the fact that the code works for some Worksheets suggests it is related to that (ie the contents of the Worksheets). Have you checked the Range that is being copied to make sure it is valid, and to see exactly what it contains ... eg step through your code or (might be simpler) add `Debug.Print rng.Parent.Name & "!" & rng.Address` immediately before `rng.Copy` and see what is different about the Range for the Worksheet that errors compared to those that are okay?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.